# Java Generics Cannot Find Symbol Confusion

Tags: java, debugging, generics, graph, compiler-errors

I am stumped on my assignment currently. I am working with Generics and am getting an error and I don't understand why it's arising. Any help would be much appreciated!

Here is the error:

```
C:\path>javac *.java
Graph.java:76: error: cannot find symbol
                String nodeLabel = node.getLabel();
                                       ^
  symbol:   method getLabel()
  location: variable node of type N
  where N is a type-variable:
    N extends Object declared in class Graph
```

I put a comment in the code below next to the line where this error is happening

And here are the relevant methods:

```
public void propogate(N node, float lambda, Graph<N,L> otherGraph) {
        //find degree of node
        int theDegree = getDegreeOfNode(node);
        //determine num of susceptible neighnbors to be infected
        int numToInfect = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < theDegree + 1; i++) {
            float calc = (newInfected + i) / infectNodesProc;
            if (compare(calc, lambda) > 0) {
                float val1 = calc - lambda;
                float val2 = lambda - ((newInfected + (i - 1)) / infectNodesProc);

                if (compare(val1, val2) < 0) {
                    numToInfect = i;
                } else {
                    numToInfect = i - 1;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        if (numToInfect > 0) {
            otherGraph.infectNeighbors(node, theDegree, numToInfect);
            
            newInfected += numToInfect;
        }
        
        infectNodesProc++;

    }
```

```
public void infectNeighbors(N node, int theDegree, int numToInfect) {
        //get equivalent node in this graph
        String nodeLabel = node.getLabel(); // THIS IS THE LINE THAT THE ERROR IS TALKING ABOUT
        Iterator<N> it = nodes.iterator();
        N theNode = null;
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            N aNode = it.next();
            if (aNode.getLabel().equals(nodeLabel)) {
                theNode = aNode;
                break;
            }
        }

        ArrayList<N> suscNeighbors = getSuscNeighbors(theNode);

        int toInfect = numToInfect;

        while (suscNeighbors.size() > 0 && toInfect > 0) {
            Random rand = new Random();
            int randInd = rand.nextInt(suscNeighbors.size());
            N removedNode = suscNeighbors.remove(randInd);
            removedNode.state = StateEnum.INFECTIOUS;
            toInfect--;
        }
    }
```

The two methods above are inside of the Graph<N,L> class.

the Node class is what the N parameter of the Generic will be when the line String nodeLabel = node.getLabel(); is called. This class exists so I know it's not a problem of finding the class in my package or anything. Also, the getLabel() method is public and accessible so it's not a problem of an incorrect access modifier, etc. I'm pretty sure it has to do with Generics. Do I have to do <N extends Node> or something like that at the top of the Graph class?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, N extends the Object class (see error), which happens when no explicit superclass is defined for your generic. That means that it only has access to the functions and variables of that class. As far as I know, the Object class does not define a method called `getLabel()` so you should probably restrict the type parameter to something like

```java
public class Graph<N extends ClassWithLabel, L> {
  ...
}
```